# Add class to specific fields in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am rendering my form using

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

in my templates.

But I would like to have some of the "p" added some classes (not all of them), so I can have some sort of grouping between my fields thanks to css.

How would you do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything even remotely beyond what Django gives you with `as_p`, you should specify the fields yourself. You'll get much more control without having to hack around. A simple template tag like [display_field](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/13/better-newforms/) will allow you just to specify each field, its label and errors with a single tag. Then you can group the fields yourself using the HTML element meant for that: a fieldset.

```
<fieldset class="my_fieldset">
    {% display_field form.field1 %}
    {% display_field form.field2 %}
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the widget and initialize it with the class you need. Like so:

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
```

Django documunation is here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

**Edit:**
Forms are best structured with fieldsets. Unfortunately django currently doesn't 'support' them. The current state is best summarized here: [Django and fieldsets on ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518966/django-and-fieldsets-on-modelform)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the class in only applied to the "input" tag, not to the "p" tag

Answer (score 0):

Create custom template tag to render the form as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question for some ideas: [Django Forms Template design classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146958/django-forms-template-design-classes)

You could probably combine the suggested approach with the [:nth-child-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) to match the paragraphs you want.

Depending on the complexity of your form i would consider to [render the form manually](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) though.