# Django Forms and Bootstrap - CSS classes and <divs>

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/2.0-wip) with Django to render forms.

`Bootstrap` can format your forms quite nicely - as long as you have the `CSS` classes it expects included.

However, my issue is that the forms generated by Django's `{{ form.as_p }}` don't render well with Bootstrap, as they don't have these classes.

For example, the output from Django:

```
    <form class="horizontal-form" action="/contact/" method="post">
        <div style='display:none'>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' 
                   value='26c39ab41e38cf6061367750ea8c2ea8'/>
        </div>
        <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" value="FOOBAR" maxlength="20" /></p>
        <p><label for="id_directory">Directory:</label> <input id="id_directory" type="text" name="directory" value="FOOBAR" maxlength="60" /></p>
       <p><label for="id_comment">Comment:</label> <textarea id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment">Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet.</textarea></p>
       <p>
           <label for="id_server">Server:</label>
           <select name="server" id="id_server">
               <option value="">---------</option>
               <option value="1" 
                   selected="selected">sydeqexcd01.au.db.com</option>
               <option value="2">server1</option>
               <option value="3">server2</option>
               <option value="4">server3</option>
           </select>
       </p>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

From what I can tell, Bootstrap requires that your forms has a `<fieldset class="control-group">`, each `<label>` has `class="control-label"`, and each `<input>` is wrapped in a `<div>`:

```
<fieldset class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="xlarge" name="input01">
        <p class="help-text">Help text here. Be sure to fill this out like so, or else!</p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

However, adding custom CSS labels to every form field in Django is rather painful:

[Add class to Django label_tag() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414679/add-class-to-django-label-tag-output)

Is there a smarter way of either using `{{ form.as_p }}`, or iterating through the fields, without having to manually specify things, or do a whole bunch of hackery?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: You could check out [django-bootstrap-form](https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form) and/or [django-bootstrap](https://github.com/earle/django-bootstrap) Do let us know which one you end up using and why!

Comment: django-bootstrap-form appears to be very light on functionality at the moment. django-bootstrap is very promising, though, and is using the correct approach for django as far as I can tell. It would definitely be worth contributing to.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158293/how-can-i-work-around-the-need-for-bootstrap-3s-form-control-class

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I like to use ["django-crispy-forms"](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) which is the successor to django-uni-form.  It's a great little API and has great support for Bootstrap.

I tend to use the template filters for quickly porting old code and quick forms, and the template tags when I need more control over the rendering.

Comment: I would consider this the "correct" answer in 2014.

Comment: I just checked the django-crispy-forms github page, and it looks active. So it's probably a decent bet. (I'm not super up to date on this, however.)

Comment: I don't like the fact that layouts are in the python code in django-crispy-forms.

Comment: Repo still looks active in 2017

Answer (score 64):

This is what I came up with:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="control-group error">
                    <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label> 
                    <div class="controls">{{ field }}
                        <span class="help-inline">
                            {% for error in  field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label> 
                    <div class="controls">{{ field }}
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                            <p class="help-inline"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That is pretty awesome! Thanks. I was hoping to also end up with an ability to get the label to be a span that is connected to the side of a textbox. I would guess that I need to install some other package to manage that.

Comment: And if you need to use this across multiple templates, use a [reusable form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates).

Comment: Awesome, very useful!

Answer (score 43):

When `django-crispy-forms` cannot be used (e.g. when the template treats individually each field of the form), jcmrgo's answer is the only way to go. Based on his answer, here is a solution for **Bootstrap 3** (leaving his version for Boostrap 2), and with **adjustment of field classes inside the template**. While field classes are not reachable from within the template with Django's standard library (which leads to that extra forms or template tags in other solutions), here is a solution that sets the right classes to field tags without having to code outside the template:

```
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    <span class="help-block">
                        {% for error in  field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Submit" %}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This needs [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) installed and `widget_tweaks` added to [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS).

Comment: As of 2015, this is the BEST answer. Especially if you're in hurry (need to deliver) and not-in-the-mood/don't-have-time to learn *yet another* library like crispy forms. Thanks a LOT sir!

Comment: As of 2016, this is still the best answer for easily integrating without having to learn crisp.

Comment: This really should be the default answer. django-crispy-forms is nice if you don't want to template your forms and have time for a large library which takes time to learn. However in the context of the original question and in the name of time to implement; this is the best answer.

Comment: To set the placeholder - if there is one defined in the form - you can do additionally `placeholder="{{ field.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }}`. Django also can provide the needed `id` by itself: `id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"` and the name by `name="{{ field.html_name }}`

Comment: @rwx the field in the code above is being generated dynamically. Where will one add the `placeholder="{{ field.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }}`

Comment: @AnupamJain e.g. if you have an input you can do <input placeholder="{{ field.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }}"/> to set the placeholder to the string defined in the django form

Comment: @rwx Right, but you cant do that in the above code since there is no `<input>` tag since the field is being generated dynamically (and the code uses template filters). I think we need to use render_field instead to render the field to be able to use a dynamic placeholder. I struggled with that yesterday and documented the finding here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111220/use-field-label-as-placeholder-with-django-widget-tweaks)

Comment: As of 2018, this is still the best answer. I like that it keeps presentation stuff in the template, as opposed to crispy forms, which forces me to put it in python code. And, I like that it is fairly straightforward to get up and running. My only suggestion is to use "render field" instead of a filter, which is described in more detail in another answer below.

Comment: As of 2020, I still use this a lot because I like how easily I can tweak every individual form field.

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
<fieldset class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {{ field }}
        <p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }} </p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: See also: form.hidden_fields and form.visible_fields

Answer (score 8):

In order to add CSS attributes to Django generated forms it's enough to use the following code in your forms.py:

```
Recepient = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Recepient', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':'combobox'}))
```

It will produce the following HTML code:

```
<label for="id_Recepient">Recepient</label>
<select id="combobox" name="Recepient">
```

Answer (score 4):

I definitely recommend https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit

Comment: This tool has been retired.  No longer relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version using django_tweaks with a better looking result. I find render_field lighter to use than adding filters. I have also added bootstrap formatted alert messages and turned off navigator validation (with novalidate). I am relatively new to Django so don't hesitate to comment if you find any non-sense

```
<form class="large" method="post" action="/suscript/" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="control-group {%if field.errors %}error{%endif%}">
                <div class="input-group controls">
                    <label class="input-group-addon control-label" id="{{field.label|safe}}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {% render_field field type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="field.label|safe" %}
                </div>
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                         <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                         </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help-inline">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

For Example, you could created a class which defines the attributes the way you want and just call it accordingly.

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Contact
      created = MyDatePicker()

class Uniform(forms):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      attrs = kwargs.pop("attrs",{})
      attrs["class"] = "span3"
      kwargs["attrs"] = attrs
      super(Uniform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyDatePicker(Uniform,forms.DateInput)
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      attrs = kwargs.pop("attrs",{})
      attrs["class"] = "datepick" 
      attrs["id"] =kwargs.get('datetag', '')
      kwargs["attrs"] = attrs
      super(MyDatePicker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap styles forms with `<div>`s rather than `<p>`s. So, if you want it to look nice, you need to go bootstrap way 100% IMHO. And here is my preferred way of doing it:

Use [django-bootstrap3](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-form) app. Example:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

<form class="signup form-horizontal" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" %}
    {% buttons submit='Sign Up &raquo;' reset='Reset Form' layout='horizontal' %}{% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Notice the `horizontal` in 1) form class attribute 2) bootstrap_form layout and 3) buttons layout.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant approach, maybe it is good to add that you can also render individual fields like so: `{% bootstrap_field form.field_name %}` and have the ability to add formsets etc.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and easiest way would be to define your own base class that extends the Django Form class, and redefine its `as_p` method to output in the format Bootstrap requires. Then change your forms to inherit from your new Form class instead of Django's.

Answer (score 1):

After going back and forth, and searching docs and stackoverflow answers, this is what I have created which worked for me.

I checked the docs for the **django-crispy-forms** and found that it doesn't support **Bootstrap 5.0 +**.

#### Forms.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import MyModel
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

#### Views.py

```py
from .models import MyModel
from .forms import RegistrationForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if r_form.is_valid():
            r_form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        r_form = RegistrationForm()

    context = {
        'form': r_form
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/signup.html', context)
```

#### Signup.html (for loop method)

```html
<form action="/signup/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input
                type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"
                class="form-control"
                id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                name="{{field.name}}"
                required
            />
            <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block py-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Signup.html (manual method)

```html
<form action="/signup/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <div class="form-floating my-1">
        <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="{{form.email.id_for_label}}"
            name="email"
            required
        />
        <label for="{{form.email.id_for_label}}">Email address</label>
    </div>
    ... next div
```

##### I have used this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sign-in/) bootstrap example, you may need to configure the css styles.

#### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166096/14682396
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647926/14682396
- [Get the type of field in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569563/get-the-type-of-field-in-django-template)

Answer (score -1):

besides what other friends said, I would recommend using 'django-widget-tweaks'.

the answer would be sth like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
      <label for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
      {{ field|add_class:"form-control" }}
      <span class="error-block">{{ field.errors }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```