# Django raise Validationerror leads to Valuetype Error

Tags: django, django-forms, validationerror

I have tried to do a type check on file uploaded by the user using the clean_field function inside the RegistrationForm class. The Validation part is working well and the redirection works only when a .kml file is uploaded. But the problem occurs when I try to upload a Non KML file. The raise ValidationError does not seem to work. Instead the following error is displayed on the browser.

```
ValueError at /startanalysis/
The view aerial_analysis.views.second_page didn't return an HttpResponse object.It returned None instead.
```

Here is my forms file

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    resolution = forms.IntegerField(label='Enter required resolution : ')
    kml = forms.FileField(label='Enter File : ')
    CHOICES = (('1' , '1'), ('2', '2'))
    field = forms.ChoiceField(label='Type of analysis :',choices=CHOICES)

    def clean_kml (self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['kml'].name.endswith('.kml'):
            raise ValidationError("Please Upload a Valid KML File")
        return self.cleaned_data['kml']
```

Here is my View Method for this page

```
def second_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/main')
    else:    
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "secondpage.html", {'head_title': 'Head','form1': form,})
```

I want the browser to just display the error message on the form field. I am quite new to Django, so I might be missing an important part. Any kind of help would be much appreciated. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/main')
```

When you're uploading a non KML file, the `request.method` is still `POST`. However, since the form raises ValidationError, the `form.is_valid()` is `False`. You don't have any logic for that scenario. So the view functions returns `None` instead of any `HttpResponse` object.

You need to add another `else` block here where you render the same form again. This time along with the form field, you should also display the errors (the error message would contain the argument you passed to `ValidationError`).

So may be add something like this in that `else` block:

```
return render(request, "secondpage.html", {'head_title': 'Head','form1': form,})
```

(Just like your normal get request)

Comment: You don't need to add an else block, just de-indent the existing `return render()`, so that it comes after the `else` instead of inside it.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea too. Unless he wants to pass additional arguments to the view from the `POST` request.

Comment: Worked! But now I need to check how to display an error message to the user! Any help in this regard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647723/django-forms-if-not-valid-show-form-with-error-message