# Check if day is valid for selected month Django forms

Tags: django, forms, date

I have a form where the user types a day (number between 1 and 31) and then selects a month from a list and then types a year.

The problem is that when a date such as (31 February) will throw the following error:

> day is out of range for month

Is there a way I can check if the day is valid for that month (and year if it is a leap year) in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you use django Forms check [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget)

btw, why don't you want to catch such errors and show above your form in other words (if you allow to choose and submit 31 and 'February')?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, I want the field to show as invalid if the date isnt correct.

Comment: @andrew_ Do you use django forms or plain html form? If first, then check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14647770/2614426

Comment: I am using django forms. I have now used SelectDateWidget as suggested and this seems to do the trick. thanks