# Django form.errors not showing up in template

Tags: python, django, forms, jinja2

I have refrenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647723/django-forms-if-not-valid-show-form-with-error-message) stackoverflow page and tried to display my forms error on the html template.
I did:

```
    {% if form.error %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

as said in the stackoverflow question I also tried simply doing:

```
{% if form.error %}
This should pop up if there is an error
{% endif %}
```

Nothing comes up regardless:
Heres my view.py code:

```python
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I am able to get the form errors onto the django console but it refuses to show up on the template.

Printing `form.errors` prints to the console: `<li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>The two password fields didn&#39;t match.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`forms.errors` fired up, but at the end, you declare a new form `form = UserCreationForm()` just before you render your view.

After checking whether the `form` is valid or not, all your *validation errors* are inside `form` instance, remember processes run as sequence, at the end, you destroy the variable `form` with `form = UserCreationForm()` so no *validation errors* anymore.

**What you can do is add this new form `form = UserCreationForm()` to else statement when your request method is `GET`** to keep having an empty form. By adding the `else` statement you avoid the new assignment of the form; after the *validation process*, it will jump to `render(request,....)` with the `form` instance containing all *validation errors*

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
     else:
         print(form.errors)
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

> Note, the correct call for **form errors** in templates is `form.errors` with *s* not `form.error`

```
{% if form.error %}  {% if form.errors %}
```

Comment: Should I create 1 form for both post and get requests ?

Comment: conventionally yes, but there are plenty other ways. you create a form with `request.POST` when request is POST, and an empty form when it's GET