# How to catch errors from form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a collapse div with login/sign-up forms. How I can catch errors if they are and show them on page?

My form in html:

```
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input 
    id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input 
    type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" 
    />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Forms: if not valid, show form with error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647723/django-forms-if-not-valid-show-form-with-error-message)

Comment: Which kind of errors do you want to catch? Where's the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Dude use the inbuilt login, it offers you with encryption of password. the method your using is little messy i would recommend to go with django inbuilt authentication. here's the link,

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html