# custom form validation errors in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

How can I pass custom form validation errors in template?

forms.py

```
    def clean_username(self):
    inputusername = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if len(inputusername) < 6:
    raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry, your username must be between 6 and 30 characters long.')
    else:
    return inputusername
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
signup_form = CreateUserForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
signup_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
if signup_form.is_valid():
signup_form.save()

context = {'signup_form':signup_form}
return render(request, 'formvalidationapp/signupform.html', context)
```

temlate

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div>
#i want to pass error here
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Forms: if not valid, show form with error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647723/django-forms-if-not-valid-show-form-with-error-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
{{signup_form.username.errors}}
```

Comment: bro in this case how can i do?  
    def clean_password(self):
        inputpassword1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        inputpassword2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if inputpassword1 != inputpassword2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password didn\'t match')
        else:
            return inputpassword1,inputpassword2