# How do I include my def clean_slug function into my views or template so that it will work and show "title alr exist"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi I have written a `def clean(self)` function in forms to make sure that if there was previously already a post with the same title, they will return a message saying that the title already exists and hence the form cannot be submitted.

Problem now:

When I enter a title that already exists and I try to create the post, all data previously input will be removed and I will be redirected to a fresh form. No errors were raised. What I want is for the error to be raised and shown to the user when I try to click on the create button so all data remains there and the user knows and can change the title before attempting the create the blog post again.

`return cleaned_data` in forms.py is not defined too...giving a nameerror

Guideline:

Note! There is NO slug field in my form. The slug is only for the url for each individual blogpost. But basically the slug consists of the title. Eg if my username is `hello` and my chief_title is `bye`, my slug will be `hello-bye`. Both the slug and the title has to be unique as you can see in the model, but there is no slug in the form.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 brief_description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            obj= form.save(commit = False)
            author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            obj.save()
            obj.members.add(request.user)
            context['success_message'] = "Updated"
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            form = CreateBlogPostForm()
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", {})
```

forms.py

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['chief_title']

    def clean(self):
        chief_title = self.cleaned_data['chief_title']
        qs = BlogPost.objects.filter(chief_title=chief_title)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Post already exists')
        return cleaned_data
```

html

```
  <form class="create-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
   {{form.non_field_errors}}  
    {% endif %}

   <!-- chief_title -->
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_title">Chief Title!</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="chief_title" id="id_title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
   </div>   {{form.chief_title.errors}}



   <button class="submit-button btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">CREATE</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: if you refresh the page obviously data is lost. Workarounds are to save that data is a session and if object exists in the session use it as initial data.

Comment: Use a form view. It will take care of that automatically by the  form_invalid method.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Would you like to share if none of the answers are offering one?

Comment: @raratiru didnt work :(

Comment: You aren't a [Dutch](https://zen-of-python.info/), are you?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create a custom validator to check if the slug exists:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_slug_exists(value):
    blog_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(slug=value)
    if blog_post.exists():
        raise ValidationError('The post with a given title already exists')
```

Then in your **form** add this **validator** to the fields validators list:

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    chief_title = forms.CharField(validators = [validate_slug_exists])
```

**UPDATE**

You can also try using `validate_unique()` in your **form** class:

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    qs = BlogPost.objects.all()

    if qs.filter(chief_title=self.chief_title).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Blog post with this title already exists")
```

Comment: hi bro, the custom validator is in views.py is it?

Comment: Anywhere you want to put it, I recommend putting it in your `forms.py` file so you don't have to import it

Comment: hey bro getting an error, I have updated the question for you to see the error

Comment: right, my mistake, check out the edited version

Comment: Hmm, try using `{{ form.non_field_errors }}.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227795/discussion-between-sldem-and-leung2).

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a ValidationError as shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/). This would then be displayed in the form for the user.

```py
    def clean_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.cleaned_data.get("chief_title")) if len(self.cleaned_data.get("slug", )) == 0 \
            else self.cleaned_data.get("slug", )
        if BlogPost.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_('Slug already exists.'), code='invalid')
        return slug
```

Comment: hello, do I need to add anything to my views.py and template? I have replaced my code with yours but basically the form still wasnt valid and no error was raised

Comment: in my form, there is only a chief_title form for them to fill, and the chief_title will be part of the slug field. Is the clean_slug function written correctly?

Comment: How are you rendering the entire form? Are you not using this approach? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: hey bro, I have updated the question and the codes in the question so hopefully everything's clearer. You could check it out to see if the problem can be solved :) @dacx

Answer (score 0):

If you set `unique = True` Django takes care of checking whether another entry already exists in the database and adds an error in `ModelForm.errors`.

This is happening in[`ModelForm.validate_unique`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f244d86962f8b34c266c3ee449f04aa312d8971e/django/forms/models.py#L413).

There is no need to bother with this method unless you want to add more info in the error, such as the url of the existing object (it will cost 1 db hit).

Otherwise, the error already exists and you can just return the form with its errors **instead of** returning a new instance of the form as you currently do in `views.py`.

Therefore the following `views.py` as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647770/2996101) should do what you are trying to do:

app/views.py:

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do your thing
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)  # context instead of {}
```

If you want to get fancier and hit the db once more, you can add the url of the existing object in the errors list as such:

project/settings.py

```
...
# If you want to provide more info
MY_UNIQUE_BLOGPOST_ERROR_MESSAGE = "This BlogPost already exists"
...
```

app/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    # ...
    slug = models.SlugField(
        blank=True, 
        unique=True, 
        error_messages={"unique": settings.MY_UNIQUE_BLOGPOST_ERROR_MESSAGE),
    )

    def get_admin_url(self):
        return reverse("admin:app_blogpost_change", args=(self.id,))
    ...
```

app/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.html import format_html
from itertools import chain
from app.models import BlogPost

class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_unique(self):
        ''' 
            If unique error exists, find the relevant object and return its url.
            1 db hit
            There is no other need to override this method. 
        '''
        super().validate_unique()
        if settings.SHOP_ENTITY_UNIQUE_ERROR in chain.from_iterable(
            self.errors.values()
        ):
            instance = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=self.instance.slug)
            admin_url = instance.get_admin_url()
            instance_name = instance.__str__()

            self.add_error(
                None,
                forms.ValidationError(
                    format_html(
                        "This entry already exists: <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",
                        admin_url,
                        instance_name,
                    ),
                    code="unique",
                ),
            )
```