# Add a message if the fields are empty in my Django app

Tags: html, django, forms, error-handling

So I have a Django form and what I want is that it shows a message under (like in red) each field if they are not filled. I have tried adding the "error_messages" attribute to my widgets in each field but it won't work.

my forms.py:

```
class WordForm(forms.Form):
Word1 = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a word'}, required = True, label= 'Word1', 
    widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': "form-control is-invalid",
        'placeholder': 'Enter First Word'
    }))
Word2 = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a word'}, required = True, label= 'Word2', 
    widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control is-invalid needs-validation was-validated',
        'placeholder': 'Enter Second Word'
    }))
Word3 = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a word'}, required = True, label= 'Word3', 
    widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control is-invalid',
        'placeholder': 'Enter Third Word'
    }))

Result = forms.CharField(label= 'Result', required=False, 
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'True'}))
```

my form.html:

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2>Inputs</h2>
            {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

As you can see, I have added the error messages field and also the is-invalid class in the widgets but It won't do anything. I don't really know if I have to create a function, cause I have seen those feedback messages but not with the form rendering. Help is much appreciated.

This is what my interface looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a template page for rendering form error messages.
Your `form_error.html` should look like this:

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h2>Inputs</h2>
  {% for field in form %}
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
      {% if field.errors %}
          {% for error in field.errors %} 
          <div class="your-css-alert-class">
              <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Then in your `view.py`,

```py
def submit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        if  form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            return render(request, 'form_error.html', {'form': form})
```

[Relevant information in the documentation for rendering error messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages)

[Didn't know this has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647723/django-forms-if-not-valid-show-form-with-error-message#14647770)

Comment: Yes you are kind of right, but does not really solve what I wanted to achieve. What I wanted is everytime I press the button, a red bootstrap text appears under each field. This help text appears everytime. @phyominh

Comment: Then you need to render your fields manually in an error template. I will update my answer on that.

Comment: Okay thank you, take your time in answering! @phyominh

Comment: I've added the codes. Let me know if they solve your problem.