# Passing widget attributes dictionary into Django Form

Tags: django

I am using forms in my Django project, and I want to specify some of the attributes of the widget that I use in my form but am having trouble figuring out how to pass in the `attrs` dictionary to the widget.

**The view.py**:

```
form_schedule_start = WINDOW_Schedule_Form(section_label=" Start",required=True,initial=scheduleStart,attributes={'class':"form-control",'placeholder':".col-md-4"})
```

**The form**:

```
class WINDOW_Schedule_Form(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    section_label = kwargs.pop('section_label')
    initial_value = kwargs.pop('initial')
    required_value = kwargs.pop('required')
    attributes = kwargs.pop('attributes')

    super(WINDOW_Schedule_Form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['WINDOW_Schedule'].label=mark_safe(section_label)
    self.fields['WINDOW_Schedule'].initial=initial_value
    self.fields['WINDOW_Schedule'].required=required_value
    self.fields['WINDOW_Schedule'].attrs=attributes


  WINDOW_Schedule = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Normally you would just do

```
WINDOW_Schedule = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center",'placeholder':".col-md-8"}))
```

but I want to be able to specify the `'class'` and `'placeholder'` attributes in my views.py.

I keep getting an error that `attributes` is not defined though.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get the error? At the point where `kwargs.pop('attributes')` is called?

Comment: @Alain yes, I get it where `kwargs.pop('attributes')` is called.

Comment: This is interesting. According to the definition of the pop()  function for dictionaries (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), a key error should be raised when you execute `required_value = kwargs.pop('required')` since there is no key 'required' and you don't assign a default.

Comment: @Alain I think that is a copy/paste error on my part.  I have `required` defined in my code - see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
This Code May Help You Out       
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Contact
      created = MyDatePicker()

class Uniform(forms):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      attrs = kwargs.pop("attrs",{})
      attrs["class"] = "span3"
      kwargs["attrs"] = attrs
      super(Uniform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyDatePicker(Uniform,forms.DateInput)
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      attrs = kwargs.pop("attrs",{})
      attrs["class"] = "datepick" 
      attrs["id"] =kwargs.get('datetag', '')
      kwargs["attrs"] = attrs
      super(MyDatePicker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Source :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474409/django-forms-and-bootstrap-css-classes-and-divs