# Style Login Form of Django-Allauth using Django-Crispy-Forms

Tags: html, css, django, forms, django-allauth

I am using django-crispy-forms to style the login form of the django-allauth login.html

```
  <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
    <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
  </form>
```

However, the form `{{ field.label }}` is not "inline" with the `{{ field }}`. Is there a simple way to make them inline while still using django-crispy-form or something similar to polish the appearance?

I also want to learn how to hide the `{{ field.label }}` on display. The only thing I can think of is to loop over the fields of forms, and comment out the label display on the following answer.

[Django Forms and Bootstrap - CSS classes and <divs>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474409/django-forms-and-bootstrap-css-classes-and-divs)

Comment: What does "the form label" mean? Do you need to hide field label in form? You can set empty labels in forms.py to achieve the desired result, like this: `somefield = forms.CharField(label='', ...)`

Comment: forms need the label. but I donot want to display them. Question is updated to clarify

Comment: The input itself can be of a hidden type, not the label. What is the reason to pass the hidden label?

Comment: say, I have a sign in field which has placeholder text "email", so the field label for email field does not need to be displayed then.

Comment: That's what I've said - you can set it to empty then. At last, you do not need it in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make labels be inline with the fields they are related to. Use custom css to rewrite `bootstrap.css`. To be more specific, you need to make `div.controls`, containing `input` and error message, display as `inline-block`:

```
div.controls{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Depending on your current page styles, what stuff (fields, labels, error msgs, etc.) you want to render on a page and how it should look (for example, in a line with error msg or not), you might need to also change width and display properties of `input.form-control` and error messages.

In order to hide labels set it to empty in forms.py:

```
somefield = forms.CharField(label='', ...)
```

This will make the label disappear.

Comment: yea, but the form rendered is from third-party package  whose fields are not easily modified.

Answer (score 0):

I found the django-widget-tweak package, which allows finer control of each field in django forms.