# Problem with ManyToManyField in other model's forms using Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, django-models, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I would like to show possible choices from ManyToManyField (which I have in Homes model) in the Owners form. I have **Owners <--Many2Many--> Homes** with custom class HomesOwners. In Homes it works out of the box, I don't know how to make it work in Owners.

I am using Django 2.2.4 with Bootstrap 4 and Postgresql. I started my project based on django-bookshelf project (also just Django and Bootstrap4). I do not use any render. Comment in django-bookshelf project mentioned [How to add bootstrap class to Django CreateView form fields in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452278/how-to-add-bootstrap-class-to-django-createview-form-fields-in-the-template), so I stick to that if it comed to forms.

I'm pretty new to Python (so Django too) and web technologies in general. I googled dozen of different questions/answers but I couldn't find any nice explanation of what is what and how to use it in real life. Most of them ended up with basic usage.

I did some experimentation on my own, but no success so far...

**Here is the code**

I have two models - **Homes/models.py** and **Owners/models.py**

**Homes/models.py:**

```py
class Homes(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   # other fields
   some_owners = models.ManyToManyField(Owners, through='HomesOwners', through_fields=('id_home', 'id_owner'), related_name='some_owners')
   # end of fields, some other code in the class like "class Meta" etc.

class HomesOwners(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   id_home = models.ForeignKey(Homes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_home')
   id_owner = models.ForeignKey('owners.Owners', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_owner')
```

**Owners/models.py** do not have anything special, no imports from my Homes/models.py etc.

and my forms:

**Homes/forms.py**:

```py
class HomesForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(HomesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['some_field_from_homes_model'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control '}
      #
      # --> no need self.fields for M2M, Django does the work
      #
      # but I tried also and have a --> Question 2
      # self.fields["some_owners"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
      # self.fields["some_owners"].queryset = HomesOwners.objects.all()
```

Without any code as **"self.fields"** for M2M field, Django is able to generate for me list of owners.

**Question 1**

I would like to get list of **Homes** in my **OwnersForms**.

I do not know what to add. I assume that I cannot add

```py
# Owners/models.py
some_homes = models.ManyToManyField(Homes, through='HomesOwners', through_fields=('id_home', 'id_owner'), related_name='some_homes')
```

because of circular import, am I right?

How do I get my Homes list using self.fields? 
What do I need to add to my code?

**Question 2**

When I've added

```py
# Homes/forms.py
self.fields["some_owners"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
self.fields["some_owners"].queryset = HomesOwners.objects.all()
```

I got

```
<!-- html page -->
HomesOwners object (1)
HomesOwners object (2)
<!-- and so on... -->
```

How can I just list Owners? 
How to filter/order them so first they would appear Owners not connected to any Home?

**Question 3**

```py
class HomesOwners(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   id_home = models.ForeignKey(Homes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_home')
   id_owner = models.ForeignKey('owners.Owners', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_owner')

def __str__(self):
   return pass #return something
```

I can't get my head around this. This class connects **Homes** and **Owners**. When I'm thinking of **Homes** I would like to return **Owners** and vice versa. So it should return different things depending on what object we are using (home or owner). I think this is connected to my 2nd question about:

```
HomesOwners object (1)
```

Also...

In **homes.html** I'm using my M2M like that:

```html
{% for owner in homes.homesowners_set.all %}
{{ owner.id_owner.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to write something similar to my **owners.html** and list homes. This is connected to my previous question, I would like to have full answer if that's possible.

**EDIT**

With the answer given to me I was able to add Homes to OwnerUpdate view. I have views like that:
**owners/views.py**

```py
# List View
class OwnersList(ListView):
    model = Owners

# Detail View
class OwnersView(DetailView):
    model = Owners

# Create View
class OwnersCreate(CreateView):
    model = Owners
    form_class = OwnersForm
    # Setting returning URL
    success_url = reverse_lazy('owners_list')

# Update View
class OwnersUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Owners
    form_class = OwnersForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('owners_list')

# Delete View
class OwnersDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Owners
    success_url = reverse_lazy('owners_list')
```

What change do I need to make to be able to show in OwnersList Homes they own?
In Homes DetailView I am able to show Owners. I would like to do the same for Homes' DetailView and Homes ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get it what you asking for,
but if I understand your question correctly,
I assume you want to add Homes list (not HomesOwners list) into your Owners form, right?

you can add extra field in your form like this:

```
class OwnersForm(ModelForm):
    # notice the queryset is 'Homes' not 'HomesOwners'
    homes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Homes.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Owners
        fields = ('homes', 'your_other_fields',)

    # then you can access in init function too if you want
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OwnersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['homes'].required = False
```

then, since it using `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget, you can iterate it in your html template like this:

```
{% for key, value in your_form.homes.field.choices %} <!-- notice '.field.'-->
{{ key }} = {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

you probably need to create custom save too for your form.

---

for your question 3, it is not about the form?
If you want to show HomesOwners, you are already doing right.

```
{% for owner in homes.homesowners_set.all %}
{{ owner.id_owner.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

but it will work if that `homes` is only 1 object.
if `homes` is a queryset, you have to iterate it first

```
{% for home in homes %}
    {% for owner in home.homesowners_set.all %}
    {{ owner.id_owner.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

sorry if I misunderstanding your questions,
maybe you can provide your `views.py` too, so I or others can help you more specific

Comment: I just played with the first part, had to modify some things, but the main thing I think is working. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: I edited my post adding one more question. Do you think you can help me with that too?

Comment: you can override `get_context_data` method in your view. see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)