# Use field label as placeholder with django-widget-tweaks

Tags: django, django-templates, django-widget-tweaks

I am using django-widget-tweaks and unable to figure out *how to add a field variable as placeholder*, like the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
 {{ field|append_attr:"class:form-control"|append_attr:"placeholder:field.label" }}
 {% if field.help_text %}
   <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
 {% endif %}
</div>
```

`field.label` above does not evaluate and puts the string `"field.label"` as the placeholder on the page.

Some SO posts suggest registering a custom tag/filter which seems complicated for something this simple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am now using `render_field` to render the field instead of using template filters and it seems to work.

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
  {% if field.help_text %}
     <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

It seems form variables cannot be used within template filters and can only be used with `render_field` (though the django-widget-tweaks [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) doesnt say that explicitly).