# MDBootstrap for Django Form Fields

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

Has anyone had any success incorporating MDBootstrap classes into their Django forms?  I have MDBootstrap working fine in my Django project, but since I am having django render my form fields I can't figure out how I could use the MDBootstrap form component styling.

Essentially if I do this it comes up with the bootstrap styling:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="First Name">
```

But since I'm rendering my forms fields like this - I can't figure out how to achieve the same cosmetic result:

```
{{form.firstname}}
```

Comment: Check this out: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474409/django-forms-and-bootstrap-css-classes-and-divs>

Answer (score 0):

You could try [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/), then it could be written as:

```
{{ form.firstname|add_class:"form-control mb-4"|attr:"type:text"|attr:"placeholder:First Name"}}
```

It creates an id, but you can also add your own as another attribute.