# Python metaclasses and special methods

Tags: python, metaclass

I experiment with metaclasses to generate the class with the custom special method - particularly, `__call__`. The generation of the class depends on the parameters the constructor was called with. I've faced a strange effect, simplified example is below:

```
def trick(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print "Works!"

class Test1Factory(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
        namespace['__call__'] = trick
        return type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)


class Test1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Test1Factory

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value


t1 = Test1(1)
t1() # "Works!"
```

It works, but it is not really useful, because there is no access to constructor arguments within `__new__`. `type.__call__` should do the trick:

```
import types
class Test2Factory(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        setattr(obj, '__call__', types.MethodType(trick, obj, Test2))

        return obj

class Test2(object):
    __metaclass__ = Test2Factory

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

t2 = Test2(2)
t2.__call__() # "Works!"
t2() # TypeError: 'Test2' object is not callable
```

As far as I understand, `instance()` is similar to `instance.__call__()`, but it is not the case here. Using `__new__` static method of the class does the same. I have a workaround that does not use metaclasses at all, but just want to understand the phenomena. Python version is 2.7.5

Comment: Special methods are looked up in class not instances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding special methods on an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary - yes, this answers the question. Using a dispatch was my workaround and I guess the only way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong assumption may be in “`instance()` is similar to `instance.__call__()`”, as `__call__` is not looked up for in `instance`, but in instance's type. That is, the `__call__` used is not that of `instance`, but that of `instance.__class__` or `type(instance)`.

Any `__call__` attribute defined on the `instance` solely, may be accessed regularly as any other attribute, but will not be used when `instance` is called as in `instance()`. That's part of Python's semantic.

Try to define a `__call__` both on an instance and on its type, and see what you get.

If I understand the question correctly, the question has the same background as another I had, and which gets an answer (summarized, with demonstrations by experiments, in the question's post) : “[How do Python tell “this is called as a function”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25771421/279335)”.