# defining __call__ of object in __init__ in Python 3.4

Tags: python, object, python-3.x, call, magic-function

I have got the following piece of code:

```
class Callable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__call__ = func
```

when I test it, I get the following result:

```
>>> square = Callable(lambda x: x**2)
>>> square(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Callable' object is not callable
>>> square.__call__(3)
9
>>>
```

furthermore, when I define a `__call__` method in the Class definition, the object is callable, but the Classes `__call__` is called although the objects `__call__` is the one I passed to the `__init__` Function:

```
class Callable:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return -x

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__call__ = func
```

Now, when testing I get:

```
>>> square = Callable(lambda x: x**2)
>>> square(3)
-3
>>> square.__call__(3)
9
>>>
```

In Python 2 this works as expected (`x(args)` calls `x.__call__(args)`).
Why doesn't this work in Python 3.4?
And how can you fix this?

**ANSWER:** I'm answering my own question after seeing why this behaves like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance).

An easy way to fix this, that doesn't affect a client is:

```
class Callable:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.__call__(x)

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__call__ = func
```

when I use this I get (as expected):

```
>>> a = Callable(lambda x: x**2)
>>> a(3)
9
```

Comment: In Python 2 to get the same behavior you need to inherit from `object`, otherwise the class will be an old-style class that allowed special methods on instances as well.