# Why is __getattr__ capable of handling built-in operator overloads in Python 2.x but not in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, class

In python 2.x take the following class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def myrepr(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('Fetching attr: %s' % attr)
        if attr=='__repr__':
            return self.myrepr
```

Now if you create an instance and echo it in the shell (to call `__repr__`), like

```
 p = Person('Bob')
 p
```

You get

```
Fetching attr: __repr__
Bob
```

Without the `__getattr__` overload you'd have just got the default `<__main__.A instance at 0x7fb8800c6e18>` kind of thing.

My question is why is the built-in `__getattr__` even capable of handling calls to `__repr__` (and other builtins like that) if they are not elsewhere defined. These are not attributes they are operators, more like methods..

(This no longer works in python 3.x so I guess they got rid of the handling by __getattr__ of the builtins.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a Python 2 or 3 thing, it's a [new-style vs old-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) thing. In old-style classes these methods had no special meaning, they were treated like simple attributes.

In new-style classes the [special methods are always looked up in the class(implicit lookup) not instance.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes)

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are
>   only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not
>   in the object’s instance dictionary.

[Old-style classes:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-old-style-classes)

> For old-style classes, special methods are always looked up in exactly
>   the same way as any other method or attribute. This is the case
>   regardless of whether the method is being looked up explicitly as in
>   `x.__getitem__(i)` or implicitly as in `x[i]`.

Related: [Overriding special methods on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)