# overriding magic methods with __getattr__

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I have a class, that is a container for members. all members are of the same type.

```
class A(int):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n

    def do(self):
        print('adding 10')
        return self.n + 10


class B:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.a = [a1, a2]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.a[0], item)


a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(5)
b = B(a1, a2)
```

the `__getattr__` overrides the `do` method:

```
In[7]: b.do()
adding 10
Out[7]: 20
```

and even overrides `__add__` when called explicitly

```
In[8]: b.__add__(1)
Out[8]: 11
```

but `__add__` fails when called as `+`

```
In[9]: b+1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'B' and 'int'
```

How can I override magic methods to work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why operators aren't handled by `__getattr__` is covered in [Why is __getattr__ capable of handling built-in operator overloads in python 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081448/why-is-getattr-capable-of-handling-built-in-operator-overloads-in-python-2-x)

> In new-style classes the special methods are always looked up in the class(implicit lookup) not instance.

My workaround (not perfect, but allows to make it work) would be to explicitly define the required dunder methods in `B`, and explicitly call `__getattr__` on them:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.a = [a1, a2]

    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.__getattr__("__add__")(other)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.a[0], item)
```

Comment: That is kind of what I did the first time, but in reality what I really need is a list of function names such as `names=['__add__','__sub__','__mul',...]` and then in the getattr I want to do `if name in names: getattr(self.a[0], name)`

Comment: I believe there should be  a more elegant way than to explicitly define all of those.

Comment: @DeanLa You could create a metaclass and override `__getattr__` there.

Comment: yes, meta class is probably better that this cheap workaround

Comment: it won't work with a metaclass' `__getattr__` either: dunder methods are required to exist "physically" on the class. A metaclass however can get a list of the desired dunder methods, and create stubs for those as the target class is created: that would work.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to add an answer to [Maximouse's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683994/overriding-magic-methods-with-getattr#comment105525338_59684171) to illustrate that metaclasses do not solve this issue. Given:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return "meta-attr"

class X(metaclass=Meta):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return "attr"
```

then these work:

```py
>>> X().__add__(X())
"attr"
>>> X.__add__(X(), X())
"meta-attr"
```

but this fails:

```py
>>> X() + X()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Derived' and 'Derived'
    ...
```

meaning metaclasses don't achieve OP's goals. Using [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html), we can see that under the hood python never even does an attribute lookup, it simply calls `BINARY_ADD`:

```py
>>> from dis import dis
>>> a, b = X(), X()
>>> dis("a + b")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

(tested on python 3.8)

Comment: That the bytecode is a `BINARY_ADD` doesn't mean anything, the dispatching mechanism (calling of user-defined methods) happens *inside* `BINARY_ADD`'s because [it's generic for many operators and has a bunch of fallbacks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/abstract.c#L926-L977) plus it needs to handle native types.

Comment: My point still stands, `__getattr__` is never called