# Iteration over Class instances using __iter__

Tags: python

I want to store all the instances of a class in a list and want to iterate over it.

I have tried the following two approaches :

## 1 Using MetaClasses

```
class ClassIter(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._ClassRegistry)
    def __len__(cls):
        return len(cls._ClassRegistry)         

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ClassIter
    _ClassRegistry = []
    def __init__(self,objname):
        self._ClassRegistry.append(self)
        self.name = objname

for x in ["first", "second", "third"]:
    MyClass(x)

for y in MyClass:
    print y.name
```

## 2 : Using **iter** in Class itself

```
class MyClass1(object):
    _ClassRegistry = []
    def __init__(self,objname):
        self._ClassRegistry.append(self)
        self.name = objname
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._ClassRegistry)

for x in ["first", "second", "third"]:
    MyClass1(x)

for y in MyClass1:
    print y.name
```

Out of both the solutions, former approach works perfectly while the later solution gives an error `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.

Can some one please explain me (in detail) why the second approach is not working and why there is a need to use metaclass to make another class iterable?

Comment: Directly related, same principles apply here: [Overriding special methods on an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10376604)

Comment: I don't understand why people keep on downvoting the Questions without mentioning any reason. I believe, I have asked a valid question here ...

Comment: I agree that the downvotes on your post appear harsh. You did show your attempt, and your expected outcome. The subject is a little esoteric.

Comment: Well, I personally downvoted because I can't even begin to understand why you think the second version would work. You're defining an instance method (you didn't even attempt to use a class method), of course that only works on the _instance_ and not on the class itself. This should be basic python knowledge for anybody working with classes; that you don't seem to know this means you did way too little research.

Comment: @l4mpi: there is always more research that could be done, and more experience gained. But that doesn't mean this question doesn't show effort to understand the issue. I don't think the bar needs to be *that* high.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't see any effort expended for finding out why it's not working. I mean, even the most basic case, defining any method on a class and then attempting to call it on the class leads to a pretty straightforward exception - you're calling a bound method but don't pass an instance to it. If OP had used the extensively documented `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` I would not have downvoted, but not even arriving at the knowledge that you can't simply call a method on the class itself just feels like a lack of research and experimentation for me.

Comment: Well, I must say that I'm a learner and I mostly learn the language by reading on net and by asking these stupid questions. I don't have any problem with down voting but my point is that it would be more helpful if you would have pointed me to some reference where I can study about them. Otherwise I would have learnt nothing but just demotivation about asking any question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special methods like `__iter__` are not looked up directly on the object, only on the *type* of the object. Python calls `type(object).__iter__(object)`, not `object.__iter__()`, effectively bypassing the normal object-first-then-type lookups (so from instance to class and from class to metaclass).

This is done to make hashing of types possible; if `hash(object)` used the `__hash__` method found directly on the object, you could never define a custom class with a `__hash__` method for the instances.

The meta class is the type of the class; just like the class is the type of an instance, so `iter(class)` looks for `type(class).__iter__()` rather than at `class.__iter__` directly.

If it *did* work that way, you could never define a `__iter__` method for your class *instances*, because `class.__iter__` would be a method and require the instance to be bound to, while there is no such instance if you are iterating over the class.

See the [*Special method lookup* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) of the Python datamodel documentation:

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

Comment: I suspect you must have meant something like "Python calls `type(object).__iter__()`, not `object.__iter__()`, effectively bypassing the normal instance-first-then-class lookups" — because what you have doesn't quite make sense regarding how methods are looked up on an object.

Comment: @martineau: Perhaps, but I suspect it is the second half of the sentence that is the confusing part here.

Comment: Don't think so. Seems like "only on the _type_ of the object" should translate to `type(object)` not `type(MyClass)`.

Comment: @martineau: ah, you are right; in the context of the rest of the paragraph that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Special method names are always invoked like this:

```
iter(foo) <--> type(foo).__iter__(foo)
```

Your first solution is compatible with this call (`type(MyClass)` is the metaclass).  Your second is not (`type(MyClass1) is type`, which has no `__iter__()` method).