# Specifics of converting a custom __repr__, __str__ on a custom python class

Tags: python

Consider the following class:

```
class ClusterAssignment(object):
def __init__(self, id, cluster):
    self.id = long(id)
    self.cluster = long(cluster)

@property
def id(self):
    return self._java_model.id()

@property
def cluster(self):
    return self._java_model.cluster()

def __str__(self):
  return self._str()

def _str(self):
    return "(%d,%d)" %(self.id(), self.cluster())

def __repr__(self):
    return self._str()
```

The attempt to override **str** and **repr** is not correct: they are unused.

```
ClusterAssignment(22, 234234)
Out[100]: <__main__.ClusterAssignment at 0x104ab3090>
```

Now there is an existing SOF that nominally addresses this topic:

[Overriding special methods on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance/10376655#10376655)

However it is not clear how to apply the solutions provided in the above case.

Specifically: how would the custom _str() be configured to be invoked when either **str** or **repr** are called?

**UPDATE** I made a typo with the **str** vs _str() method when simplifying this to present on SOF. The same result occurs with the corrected code - which is updated above.

Comment: You never defined _str or __str; does the provided code even run? Where is self._java anything declared or stored on the cluster? What actually is happening in your code, is this Python?

Comment: You define `__str__(self)` twice.. why?

Comment: You can't override a method in the same class it's defined, only in a subclass.  Did you mean "overload"?  In case you did: Python doesn't overload at all.  If you define a method twice in one class, even if the return type and parameters are different, the second definition simply replaces the first.)

Comment: @TimCastelijns  I updated the OP: had made a typo in my simplification of original code. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of four ways to produce "identical" `__str__` and `__repr__` methods... not counting awfulness like copy & paste.

(For these examples, I'm using a stripped-down `ClusterAssignment` class with a meaningless string representation and no other methods.)

You can use Tim Castelijns' method, with a single "private" `_str` method, called by both `__str__` and `__repr__`:

```
class ClusterAssignment(object):

    def _str(self):
        return "[string]"

    def __str__(self):
        return self._str()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._str()
```

This works, but requires repeating yourself in the bodies of the two functions.

To avoid the repetition, you can write one of `__str__` or `__repr__` normally, and then have the other method do nothing but call the "real" method.  Which method you write "for real" depends on your intended output --- is it more "stringy" or more "repr-y"?

There are then two ways to "call the 'real' method": using the dunder-method (first example below), or using the public interface (second example).  I suggest using the public interface, since that's what your users have to do.

```
class ClusterAssignment(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "[string]"

    def __repr__(self):
        # Uses "private" dunder-method.
        return self.__str__()


class ClusterAssignment(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "[string]"

    def __repr__(self):
        # Uses public interface.
        return str(self)
```

Finally, you can give the one "real" method an alias:

```
class ClusterAssignment(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "[string]"

    __repr__ = __str__
```

No repetitions here, and no redundant method definition: `__repr__` *is* `__str__`.

I think this is explicit (better than implicit) --- there is only one task performed, so there is only one method.  Others might see this as the opposite --- there are now two names masquerading as two methods, when there is really only one.  Also, their order in the source code now matters --- `__repr__` *must* be defined after `__str__`.

One quirk of the aliasing technique:  The string representations of the *methods themselves* are now identical too.  The first three versions produce:

```
>>> ca = ClusterAssignment()
>>> print(ca.__str__)
<bound method ClusterAssignment.__str__ of [string]>
>>> print(ca.__repr__)
<bound method ClusterAssignment.__repr__ of [string]>
```

The aliased version makes it clear that there is only one method:

```
>>> ca = ClusterAssignment()
>>> print(ca.__str__)
<bound method ClusterAssignment.__str__ of [string]>
>>> print(ca.__repr__)
<bound method ClusterAssignment.__str__ of [string]>
```

...or it sends your co-workers hunting for the bugged-up line that's calling `__str__` when it should be calling `__repr__`.

This kind of decision is what project style guides are for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a couple mistakes implementing the workaround in your own code, and what you actually want is more like this

```
def __str__(self):
    return self._str()

def __repr__(self):
    return self._str()

def _str(self):
    return "(%d,%d)" %(self.id(), self.cluster())
```

So that whenever `__str__()` or `__repr__()` are called, they return the result of `_str()`