# Why is __getattr__ not called for indexing operations?

Tags: python, getattr

**My question:**

It seems that `__getattr__` is not called for indexing operations, ie I can't use `__getattr__` on a class `A` to provide `A[...]`.  Is there a reason for this? Or a way to get around it so that `__getattr__`  can provide that functionality without having to explicitly define `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, etc on `A`?

**Minimal Example:**

Let's say I define two nearly identical classes, `Explicit` and `Implicit`.  Each creates a little list `self._arr` on initiation, and each defines a `__getattr__` that just passes all attribute requests to `self._arr`.  The only difference is that `Explicit` also defines `__getitem__` (by just passing it on to `self._arr`).

```
# Passes all attribute requests on to a list it contains
class Explicit():
   def __init__(self):
        self._arr=[1,2,3,4]
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        print('called __getattr_')
        return getattr(self._arr,attr)
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self._arr[item]

# Same as above but __getitem__ not defined
class Implicit():
    def __init__(self):
        self._arr=[1,2,3,4]
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        print('called __getattr_')
        return getattr(self._arr,attr)
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> e=Explicit()
>>> print(e.copy())
called __getattr_
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(hasattr(e,'__getitem__'))
True
>>> print(e[0])
1
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> i=Implicit()
>>> print(i.copy())
called __getattr_
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(hasattr(i,'__getitem__'))
called __getattr_
True
>>> print(i.__getitem__(0))
called __getattr_
1
>>> print(i[0])
TypeError: 'Implicit' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Because that's how Python was designed. `__getattr__` is used for attribute access and `__getitem__` is used for indexing access. Each has a specific role. I'm not sure what the question is

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10376655/2096752) explains it.

Comment: As for why they're separate operations, consider this: `d = {'keys': 0}` In this case, `d.keys` and `d['keys']` are very different things

Comment: how could python guess that accessing an index of `Implicit` accesses an index of one of its members? it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @shx2 Thank you, that's exactly my confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python bypasses `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, and the instance dict when looking up "special" methods for implementing language mechanics. (For the most part, special methods are ones with two underscores on each side of the name.) If you were expecting `i[0]` to invoke `i.__getitem__(0)`, which would in turn invoke `i.__getattr__('__getitem__')(0)`, that's why that didn't happen.

Comment: For anyone looking, @shx2 's comment above links to [a question with a reference for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10376655/2096752).