# Python: how to overwrite what print(dict) outputs?

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

I have a dictionary, and a print statement as follows:

```
d = {'ar':4, 'ma':4, 'family':pf.Normal()}
print(d)
```

Which gives me

```
{'ar': 4, 'ma': 4, 'family': <pyflux.families.normal.Normal object at 0x11b6bc198>}
```

**Is there any way to clean up the value of the 'family' key?** It's important that the calls remains simply 'print(d)' because it used to print other dictionaries without this issue. Is this possible? Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer guys, I would mark one as right but I haven't tried them and can't confirm. I ended up creating another dictionary with the cleaned up string as a key, and the object as the value. It was a bit more work but I did it before reading/getting the responses so I just stuck to it. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: You don't want to chage what `print(dict)` outputs, you want to add a `__repr__()` function to `pf.Normal()` to change how _it_ is displayed. I'm not sure what exactly `pf.Normal()` is , but perhaps inherit from it and add a custom `__repr__()`?

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken. You don't want to change what `print(dict)` outputs. That would require changing the way builtin dictionaries are printed. You want to add a custom `__repr__()` to your `pf.Normal()` object.

[I believe `pf.Normal()` comes from the `pyflux` package](http://www.pyflux.com/docs/families.html#Normal), so I suggest seeing what data the class is suppose to hold, and pretty printing it by inheriting from the class:

```
class CustomNormalObject(pf.Normal):
    def __repr__(self):
        # Add pretty printed data here
        pass
```

Or if you need to pass your own arguments into the custom class, you can use `super()`:

```
class CustomNormalObject(pf.Normal):
    def __init__(self, myparm, *args, **kwargs):
        # If using Python 3, you can call super without
        # passing in any arguments. This is simply for Python 2
        # compatibility.
        super(CustomNormalObject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myparm = myparm

    def __repr__(self):
        # Add pretty printed data here
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

as I think `pyflux` is an external library, I think you should not edit it directly. An easy way to do what you want is to overwrite the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods of the `Normal` class.

```
pyflux.families.normal.Normal.__str__ = lambda self: "Clean up value here."
```

Here I used a lambda function for illustration, but of course you can use a defined function.

Comment: Monkey patching special methods may not work - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance

Comment: @PeterGibson this is fine because it's being monkey-patched *on the class*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you're right. Should work sorry.

Comment: Ghilas, I went ahead and rolled-back your last edit. This is a good answer and definitely solves the problem in a pinch.