# How to override __eq__ only at instance level?

Tags: python, overriding

for example, I have this class and two instances of it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version

a1 = A('1.0')
a2 = A('1.0')
```

because there is no direct way to compare `a1` and `a2`. I override the `__eq__` method of both instances using MethodType.

```
def compare(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        raise TypeError
    return self.version == other.version

a1.__eq__ = MethodType(compare, a1, a1.__class__)
a2.__eq__ = MethodType(compare, a2, a2.__class__)
```

However, after all these effort, `a1 == a2` still returns `False`.

After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order), I get that in order for `==` to be overridden, one must override the `__eq__` method for the class, not the instance.

**One of the reasons why I don't do this at class level is that doing so would pollute the class, I only produce instances using some functions(not sub-classes) and adding attributes dynamically for comparison.**

I want to know if there is a way to override `==` at instance level without change the class.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878846/monkey-patching-eq-in-python

Comment: Why not to override at the class level?

Comment: @balderman updated my question for your question.

Comment: @Sajuuk I read you addition to the post and I still dont understand.. If the natural way to tell if 2 instances of A are the same (a1 == a2) is to compare their versions it looks very natural (in my eyes) to implement `__eq__`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding special methods on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)

Comment: @balderman maybe I had gone stray, what I did is having mulitple functions producing instances of the same class but adding different attributes correspondingly, thus the difference. I want to make sure instances produced by same function test equal.

Comment: @quamrana that question provided some insight indeed. looks like I have to override `__eq__` at class level to capture method bound to instance..

Comment: Yes, once you have written `__eq__` at a class level to redirect to an instance method, that instance method can be overridden at any time after an instance has been created, but before `==` is used.

Comment: @quamrana yeah and that led to another problem is how can I save original `__eq__` as a fallback.. which is 'equally' tricky..

Comment: You need to ask another question about this. Sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: @quamrana already done yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129685/how-to-access-a-method-inside-a-class