# How to access a method inside a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Environment: Python 2.7 (Might be related).

for example, I want to call class original `__repr__` method depending on if an attribute on instance has been set.

```
class A(object):
    # original_repr = ?__repr__

    def __init__(self, switch):
        self.switch = switch

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.switch:
            return self._repr()
        else:
            # return saved original __repr__ method.


def custom_repr(self):
    pass

a = A()
a._repr = MethodType( custom_repr, a, A)
```

**How do I save the `__repr__` method of the class?**

obviously I can't use `self` like in an instance.

Can't use `A.__repr__` either, since `A` itself is not defined at that time.

EDIT: someone suggested using `super().__repr__`, however, I tested it in code:

```
class C(object):
    pass

class D(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return super(self.__class__).__repr__()

c = C()
d = D()

# repr(c) --> '<__main__.C object at 0x0000000003AEFBE0>'
# repr(d) --> "<super: <class 'D'>, NULL>"
```

you can see that `super().__repr__` is not the same as the original `__repr__`

Comment: i think you can get away with `A._repr = my_func` but you have to do it BEFORE you do get any instances, but the important questions is WHY do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Use `super().__repr__()`

Comment: @Nullman for the glory of Santa of course...well actual reason is that I'm overriding the `__eq__` magic method in some instances but not others, so I need a default `__eq__` method to fallback to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fallback on the `__repr__` method of the super-class via `super().__repr__()`. I will show an example below by subclassing a new class.

So if we have a parent `class B` as follows, with it's own `__repr__` defined

```
class B:

    def __repr__(self):

        return 'This is repr of B'
```

And then we have a child `class A` as before, which inherits from `B`, it can fall back to `__repr__` of B as follows

```
class A(B):

    def __init__(self, switch):
        super().__init__()
        self.switch = switch

    def __repr__(self):
        #If switch is True, return repr of A
        if self.switch:
            return 'This is repr of A'
        #Else return repr of B by calling super
        else:
            return super().__repr__()
```

You can test out this by doing

```
print(A(True))
print(A(False))
```

As expected, the first case will trigger the `__repr__` of A, and the second case will trigger the `__repr__` of B.

```
This is repr of A
This is repr of B
```

If A is just a normal class which inherits from object, the code will change to

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, switch):
        super().__init__()
        self.switch = switch

    def __repr__(self):
        #If switch is True, return repr of A
        if self.switch:
            return 'This is repr of A'
        #Else return repr of superclass by calling super
        else:
            return super().__repr__()
```

And the output will change to

```
print(A(True))
#This is repr of A
print(A(False))
#<__main__.A object at 0x103075908>
```

Comment: what if I have no parent class to fallback to and just want to save the `__repr__` of current class?

Comment: You mentioned `I want to call class original __repr__ method`, if you don't have a parent class, the `__repr__` of object class will be printed which is something like `<__main__.A object at 0x103275908>` @Sajuuk Also not sure what you mean by `saving` the `__repr__` method?

Comment: I want to make sure one thing:
X:  `__repr__` of a parent-less class
Y: calling from instance of this class like `super(self.__class__).__repr__ 

is X and Y the same?

Comment: check my updated answer and see if it makes sense to you now! Yes X and Y are same, they look like.   `<__main__.ClassName object at 0x....>` since it calls `__repr__` of `object` class @Sajuuk

Comment: What is this then?  `<super: <class 'D'>, NULL>` # from output of using `super().__repr__()` in overidden `__repr__`   you can see my updated question.

Comment: Ohh sorry, you shoud not use `super(self.__class__).__repr__()` but use 
 `super().__repr__()` . Doing `super(self.__class__).__repr__()` is calling super of D again since `self.__class__=<class '__main__.D'>` @Sajuuk

Comment: unfortunately I'm limited to using python2.7,  `super().__repr__()` would raise an exception "TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: Aah okay you didn't mention python2.7 anywhere, let me check for python2.7 @Sajuuk, what about `super(object, self).__repr__()` ? Or `super(self.__class__, self).__repr__()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193346/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-sajuuk).

Comment: It turns out super() if used with`__eq__` will throw attribute error, because unlike '__repr__` which every object has,  parent class has no `__eq__` .  so I would need another way to save '__eq__` for the current class...

Comment: Aah okay, perhaps using `__eq__` with `__super` might be better suited if for a new question for the same. This way you will also get responses from other users as well @Sajuuk :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for,

```
super().__repr__()


class A:
    # original_repr = ?__repr__

    def __init__(self, switch):
        self.switch = switch

    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__()
```

Comment: when I test it in code, this solution returned different repr than a class with `__repr__` not overidden. 
yours return :  "<super: <class 'A'>, NULL>"
original return: "'<__main__.A object at 0x00000000033D0AC8>'

which means the target of "saving" original method is not achieved.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __repr__(self):
        if self.switch:
            return "Hello"
        return super().__repr__()
```