# Adding a magic method to an existing object instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

How do I add magic method to an existing object using partial?
(I understand that adding methods to an existing object is not a recommended concept.)

Here's what I've tried

```
from functools import partial 
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 10

def my_function(obj):
  return str(obj.value)

obj = Foo()
obj.__repr__ = partial(my_function, obj)
print(repr(obj))         # <__main__.A object at 0x7ff612e62bb0>
print(obj.__repr__())    # 10
```

I was expecting `print(repr(obj))` also prints 10, but it just returned memory address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Please [edit] and fix the indenting of your code. At the moment, you have an `IndentationError` at `self.value = 10`. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: `partial` is in `functools`. `from functools import partial`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding special methods on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)