# Why monkey patching (via setattr) magic methods does not work?

Tags: python

`x` is an instance of some object:

```
> x = type('someobject', (), {})()
> repr(x)
<someobject object at 0x10172d990>
```

Why monkey patching a magic method (e.g. `__repr__`) does not work?

```
> setattr(x, '__repr__', lambda self: f'<someobj {id(self)}>')
> repr(x)
<someobject object at 0x10172d990>
```

(original `__repr__` is used)

```
> x.__repr__(x)
<someobj 4319271312>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding special methods on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `repr` object on the type, not the class itself:

```py
x = type('someobject', (), {})()
print(repr(x))
# <__main__.someobject object at 0x7f91c2c664d0>
type(x).__repr__=lambda self: f'<someobj {id(self)}>'
print(repr(x))
# <someobj 140264014767312>
```

Special methods work a bit weired this way.

You can monkey patch a single instance like this:

```py
def override_repr(obj):
    # create a new subclass that inherits from the objects original type
    new_type = type(type(obj).__name__, (type(obj),), {})
    # Override the repr special method
    new_type.__repr__ = lambda self:hex(id(self))
    # change the type of the object to the new subtype
    obj.__class__=new_type

class M:
   pass

k = M()
override_repr(k)
print(repr(k))
```

Comment: Thanks! What about monkey patching only one instance's magic method? Not possible?

Comment: Create a anonymous subclass for that one instance, so it will have it's own private type

Answer (score 2):

They intentionally treated differently. It's documented though:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only
> guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s **type**, not in
> the object’s instance dictionary. That behaviour is the reason why the
> following code raises an exception:
> ...

You can read the rest to understand the reason:

> The rationale behind this behaviour lies with a number of special methods such as `__hash__()` and `__repr__()` that are implemented by all objects, including type objects. If the implicit lookup of these methods used the conventional lookup process, they would fail when invoked on the type object itself:
>
> ```py
> >>> 1 .__hash__() == hash(1)
> True
> >>> int.__hash__() == hash(int)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: descriptor '__hash__' of 'int' object needs an argument
> ```