# Define __getitem__() wthin class constructor

Tags: python, constructor

Python allows assigning function definitions to class members directly like,

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.test = lambda x: print(x)

a = A()
a.test(10) # prints 10
```

However for `__getitem__(self, idx)` it's not that simple. Say you have two possible implementations for `__getitem__` depending on a flag variable. One could simply write,

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, N, flag):
    self.values = list(range(N))
    self.flag = flag
  def __getitem__(self, idx).
    if flag: 
      return self.values[idx]
    else:
      return self.values[idx] * self.N    # toy example

a = A(10, True)
a[5] # returns 6
```

But if I want to avoid doing the if-else logic wihthin `__getitem__` say for example in a data oriented application, I'd like to be able to do that test in the constructor. Something like,

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, N, flag):
    self.values = list(range(N))
    self.flag = flag
    self.N = N
    if flag: 
      self.__getitem__ = lambda self, idx: return self.values[idx]
    else:
      self.__getitem__ = lambda self, idx: return self.values[idx] * self.N

a = A(10, False)
a[5] # should return 12, instead yields NotImplementedError
```

However this last snippet yields a NotImplementedError. Is there a way to do this or does python already optimize if-else blocks like the one above ?

Comment: `a[5]` *always* means `type(a).__getitem__(5)`, whether or not an instance attribute named `__getitem__` exists.

Comment: 1) Consider the use of `__new__` and return different types for different implementations. 2) Set a callable member in `__init__` and call it from `__getitem__` unconditionally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance

Comment: Consider whether you need the flag at all. In this example, you could take advantage of the fact that 1 is the multiplicative identity and *unconditionally* multiply `self.values[idx]` by an appropriate value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the conditions only in the constructor, then maybe rearranging lambda functions can help you.

For example,

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, N, flag):
        self.values = list(range(N))
        self.flag = flag
        if flag:
            self.cond = lambda idx:  self.values[idx]
        else:
            self.cond = lambda idx : self.values[idx] * 2

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.cond(item)

a = A(10, False)
print(a[5]) # returns 5 x 2 = 10
```