# Use IronPython to override DLL function

Tags: python, .net, dll, ironpython

I would like to use IronPython to override a method from a dll, so that all future calls to that method go to the python implementation instead. I was hoping to base it on the technique from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829200/override-module-method-where-from-import-is-used).

So I tried making a dll with just the following class:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string test()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did the following in IronPython:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("ClassLibrary1")

import ClassLibrary1

def _override():
    return "george"

ClassLibrary1.Class1.test = _override;

print ClassLibrary1.Class1.test();
```

However, when running the python code, I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Snippets.debug.scripting but was not handled in user code

Additional information: attribute 'test' of 'Class1' object is read-only
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: have you tried overriding a non-static dll method?

Comment: @RolandAskew Identical error message

Comment: if use win7, need give permission for working. [Run as Administrator CMD] takeown /f  your_path_to_dll  AND check your dll filestat (maybe only readonly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend Roland's answer, consider writing a wrapping python module. I have never worked with IronPython, but I believe you can fix the solution if an issue appears.

```
# class_library_1_wrapper.py
import clr
clr.AddReference("ClassLibrary1")
import ClassLibrary1 


class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._clr_object = ClassLibrary1.Class1()

    def some_method():
        return self._clr_object.SomeMethod()

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        return "george"
```

This approach is suggested by Cython developers [when importing C++ classes](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class). The other benefit is you weaken your dependency on `"ClassLibrary1"` and can fallback to pure IronPython implementation of `Class1` without letting other modules know:

```
# class_library_1_wrapper.py
import clr
clr.AddReference("ClassLibrary1")

try:
    import ClassLibrary1
except ImportError:
    print 'sorry, no speed-ups'
    # Class1 IronPython implementation here
else:
    # Implement Class1 as described in the first snippet.
```

This approach can be found in Werkzeug Python library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is called a [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch). It is not actually an override, but a dynamic replacement of an attribute at runtime.

Monkey patching is specific to python, so it isn't guaranteed for non-python classes.

Instead, look into deriving a new python class from your C# class, and override the method there.