# How can you change the default anchor, relx and rely for placing tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, default, default-value

Many widgets in my program are placed like so:

```
widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

So, I wanted to make this the default setup. I have tried:

```
root.option_add("*anchor", "center")#Putting CENTER returns an error
root.option_add("*relx", "0.5")
root.option_add("*rely", "0")
```

However, this does not work.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I think you _can_ [override the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10829200/7032856) `place` for your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the default options without overriding the method, but a viable workaround would be simply defining a variable for that `customization` and simply pass that to the widgets that use it:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    customization = dict(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    my_list_of_widgets = list()
    for i in range(30):
        my_list_of_widgets.append(tk.Label(root, text=i))
        my_list_of_widgets[i].place(**customization)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The option database is for specifying widget attributes, not arguments to functions. There is no built-in mechanism for specifying the arguments to `pack`, `place`, `grid`, or any other tkinter functions.

Comment: Are fonts widget attributes?

Comment: @MilanTom: yes.

Comment: So widget attributes are those that are specified in the actual widget's parameters. Eg: `Label(widget_attribute=x)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the option database @BryanOakley?

Comment: @MilanTom: you can create your own custom command that calls the built-in command with whatever options you want.