# Override a class method when it is returned from a function call

Tags: python

I know how to override class methods ([an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)) but sometimes you get a class object as an instance returned from a function call (do I say this correctly?) Now want to change one of the methods of such returned instance (or the whole class for that matter). How do I do this? I know one can override instance methods as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394770/override-a-method-at-instance-level), but it's said that is not a clean way of doing it.

My case:

```
import pyodbc
import logging

class MyDataBase(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()
    # Now I want to override the cursor method execute

    def self.cur.execute(self, sql_str):
        logging.debug(sql_str)
        super(cursor.execute)
```

Obviously this code is not quite right, consider it pseudo code. Question really is how to enhance the execute method for the cursor object.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Im certain there is a better way.

Comment: As the accepted answer to the other question says, what is "not clean" is the *concept* of changing a method on just one instance of a class.  If you need to do it, you can do it as shown in another answer to that question, but you're not going to find a "nice" way to do it because it's not really a nice thing to do.  You could instead create your own class that wraps `self.cur`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, What would the better way be?

Comment: @BrenBarn, I'd like to change the whole class, but how do I do if its only returned upon a function call?

Comment: @Bastiaan: Why do you need to change `cur.execute` instead of just giving your MyDataBase class its own `execute` method that internally does the logging and then calls `cur.execute` behind the scenes?

Comment: @BrenBarn I'd like to pass on all other methods of the cursor object including all those that I don't quite know of. But ok, considering there isn't much of an answer I guess that's the only way there is.

Comment: Strange though, all tutorials on class inheritance bloat about how great it is one can add on to existing classes. Now I want to add to pyodbc but can't, just because the class cannot be called directly.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a prime case for using decorators, or you could just write a method in MyDataBase that takes the SQL string as an argument, logs it, then calls `self.cur.execute`. This would be the preferred way, in my opinion, over extending/overriding a third party object.