# Difference between foo.bar() and bar(foo)?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

    def show_info(self):
        print("Last Name - "+self.last_name)
        print("Eye Color - "+self.eye_color)

billy_cyrus = Parent("Cyrus", "blue")
```

The above is from the [Udacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udacity) Python course. I discovered I'm able to call `show_info` for instance `billy_cyrus` using either of the following:

```
billy_cyrus.show_info()
Parent.show_info(billy_cyrus)
```

I'm curious as to why. Is there a difference between the two methods? If so when would one be used vs. the other? I'm using Python 3.6 if that matters.

Comment: There's no difference at all. The first one is kind if syntactic sugar for the latter one. That's where the `self` parameter is from. It can, however, be useful when you want to pass a method around as a parameter (e.g. for `map` or for a callback) to use either `Class.method` or `instance.method` (the latter being a bound method).

Comment: @tobias_k. That is not strictly, pedantically 100% true.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's why it's a comment and not an answer. Feel free to elaborate.

Comment: I am drafting an answer as we speak :) I think this is an important question to ask.

Comment: For your reading pleasure: [9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) from the Tutorial.

Comment: It's useful to be able to deal with objects without knowing their exact class. `Parent.show_info(billy_cyrus)` breaks down if someone wants to pass in a `Grandparent` or a `Guardian` in place of a `Parent`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. You could always do `type(billy_cyrus).show_info(billy_cyrus)`.

Comment: @ChrisDecker. You should consider selecting an answer. You get points for it, the question  gets marked as answered, the answerer gets points, and it's just the courteous thing to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of just calling the method, there is no difference most of the time. In terms of how the underlying machinery, works, there is a bit of a difference.

Since `show_info` is a [method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), it is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) in the class. That means that when you access it through an [instance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) in which it is not shadowed by another [attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), the `.` operator calls [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) on the descriptor to create a bound method for that instance. A bound method is basically a closure that passes in the `self` parameter for you before any of the other arguments you supply. You can see the binding happen like this:

```
>>> billy_cyrus.show_info
<bound method Parent.show_info of <__main__.Parent object at 0x7f7598b14be0>>
```

A different closure is created every time you use the `.` operator on a class method.

If you access the method through the class object, on the other hand, it does not get bound. The method is a descriptor, which is just a regular attribute of the class:

```
>>> Parent.show_info
<function __main__.Parent.show_info>
```

You can simulate the exact behavior of binding a method before calling it by calling its `__get__` yourself:

```
>>> bound_meth = Parent.show_info.__get__(billy_cyrus, type(billy_cyrus))
>>> bound_meth
<bound method Parent.show_info of <__main__.Parent object at 0x7f7598b14be0>>
```

Again, this will not make any difference to you in 99.99% of cases, since functionally `bound_meth()` and `Parent.bound_meth(billy_cyrus)` end up calling the same underlying function object with the same parameters.

**Where it matters**

There are a couple of places where it matters how you call a class method. One common use case is when you override a method, but want to use the definition provided in the parent class. For example, say I have a class that I made "immutable" by overriding [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__). I can still set attributes on the instance, as in the `__init__` method shown below:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'a', a)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise ValueError('I am immutable!')
```

If I tried to do a normal call to `__setattr__` in `__init__` by doing `self.a = a`, a `ValueError` would be raised every time. But by using `object.__setattr__`, I can bypass this limitation. Alternatively, I could do `super().__setattr__('a', a)` for the same effect, or `self.__dict__['a'] = a` for a very similar one.

@Silvio Mayolo's answer has another good example, where you would deliberately want to use the class method as a function that could be applied to many objects.

Another place it matters (although not in terms of calling methods), is when you use other common descriptors like [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property). Unlike methods, properties are [data-descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). This means that they define a `__set__` method (and optionally `__delete__`) in addition to `__get__`. A property creates a virtual attribute whose getter and setter are arbitrarily complex functions instead of just simple assignments. To properly use a property, you have to do it through the instance. For example:

```
class PropDemo:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__dict__['x']
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Not negatives, please!')
        self.__dict__['x'] = value
```

Now you can do something like

```
>>> inst = PropDemo()
>>> inst.x
0
>>> inst.x = 3
>>> inst.x
3
```

If you try to access the property through the class, you can get the underlying descriptor object since it will be an unbound attribute:

```
>>> PropDemo.x
<property at 0x7f7598af00e8>
```

On a side note, hiding attributes with the same name as a property in `__dict__` is a neat trick that works because data descriptors in a class `__dict__` trump entries in the instance `__dict__`, even though instance `__dict__` entries trump non-data-descriptors in a class.

**Where it can Get Weird**

You can override a class method with an instance method in Python. That would mean that `type(foo).bar(foo)` and `foo.bar()` don't call the same underlying function at all. This is irrelevant for [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) because they always use the former invocation, but it can make a big difference for normal method calls.

There are a few ways to [override a method on an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394770/2988730). The one I find most intuitive is to set the instance attribute to a bound method. Here is an example of a modified `billy_cyrus`, assuming the definition of `Parent` in the original question:

```
def alt_show_info(self):
    print('Another version of', self)

billy_cyrus.show_info = alt_show_info.__get__(billy_cyrus, Parent)
```

In this case, calling the method on the instance vs the class would have *completely* different results. This only works because methods are *non-data* descriptors by the way. If they were data descriptors (with a `__set__` method), the assignment `billy_cyrus.show_info = alt_show_info.__get__(billy_cyrus, Parent)` would not override anything but would instead just redirect to `__set__`, and manually setting it in b
`billy_cyrus`'s `__dict__` would just get it ignored, as happens with a property.

**Additional Resources**

Here are a couple of resources on descriptors:

- Python Reference - Descriptor Protocol: http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderdsc/
- (Official?) Descriptor HowTo Guide: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Answer (score 6):

There is no semantic difference between the two. It's entirely a matter of style. You would generally use `billy_cyrus.show_info()` in normal use, but the fact that the second approach is allowed permits you to use `Parent.show_info` to get the method as a first-class object itself. If that was not allowed, then it would not be possible (or at least, it would be fairly difficult) to do something like this.

```
function = Parent.show_info
so_many_billy_cyrus = [billy_cyrus, billy_cyrus, billy_cyrus]
map(function, so_many_billy_cyrus)
```

Comment: If by "fairly difficult" you mean "use `lambda b: b.show_info()`"... but, yes, that's one case where that style could be preferred.

Comment: I'm curious - if you were intending to use `show_info` like that wouldn't you define it outside of the class as a standalone function and not as an instance attribute?

Comment: @wwii It is possible that you do not have control over the source code of `show_info`. I frequently work with codebases written by people who are significantly invested in the object-oriented ideas of Java, so every API call ends up, for better or worse, being a method.

Comment: In fact, my first ever programming class (which was taught in Python) taught me that standalone functions are poor design and should never be used. Of course, that's a rather peculiar ideology, but nonetheless some people are trained on that rhetoric.

Comment: In general, `map` is equivalent to a list comprehension, so `[x.show_info() for x in so_many_billy_cyrus]` would work just fine. But that only emphasizes your original point about equivalence, so +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm sure you meant "_in Python 2_, `map` is equivalent to a list comprehension". You know, being strictly pedantically 100% correct...;-)

Comment: In Python3, replace `[]` with `()` to get the equivalent generator expression. My mistake.

Comment: @wwii. That is something I have actually dealt with quite a bit while doing unholy things with the logging system. I've addressed instance level overrides in my answer. By the time someone gets comfortable doing stuff like that though, they usually won't need it spelled out. That's why I prefer this answer.