# Cannot overwrite implementation for __call__

Tags: python

Take this as an example:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, msg):
      self._msg = msg
   def __call__(self):
      return self._msg

foo = Foo('hello')
print(foo()) # Prints 'hello'
foo.__call__ = lambda _: 'bye'
print(foo()) # Prints 'hello'
```

I can reproduce this on both *Python 2.x* and *Python 3.x*

I was not able to find any relevant information on the documentation regarding this behavior.

This totally looks like a valid use case for me, specially when monkeypatching stuff.

Is there a reason this is not allowed?

Comment: @khelwood Silly me :) You're completely right, that makes sense

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394770/override-a-method-at-instance-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call an object with `()`, it executes the `__call__` method defined on the object's type. So `__call__` is defined on the class `Foo`, not on your instance `foo`. If you reassigned `Foo.__call__`, it would work.

```
Foo.__call__ = lambda _: 'bye'
print(foo()) # prints 'bye'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "instance methods", but the key issue here is that it's a "special" (dunder) method and `()` looks up `__call__` on the class.  You can certainly override an individual instance's implementation of a "regular" method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self._msg = msg
    def __call__(self):
        return self._msg

foo = Foo('hello')
print(foo()) # Prints 'hello'

Foo.__call__ = lambda _: 'bye' #Notice the capital F, this is the class not the instance
print(foo()) # Prints 'bye'
```

The last call should print 'bye' like you expect. When you call an instance's functions, it's actually referring to the class functions (where they are defined)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can do this.  Override a single instance's implementation of a given method without affecting the rest.

The problem here is that you're attempting to override a "special" method.  The `()` call syntax looks up the `__call__` method on the class, not the instance.

The following code shows that you can override a single instance's method implementation, as well as serves as sort of an ugly workaround to your problem:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self._msg = msg
    def __call__(self):
        return self.call()      # Delegate call to instance
    def call(self):
        return self._msg

foo = Foo('hello')
other = Foo('hi')

print(foo()) # Prints 'hello'

def new_call(self):
    return "bye"

foo.call = new_call.__get__(foo, Foo)
print(foo()) # Prints 'bye'

print(other()) # Prints 'hi' (unaffected by override)
```

Note: the following also would work as you expect:

```
foo.call = (lambda _: "bye").__get__(foo, Foo)
```

But I prefer the explicit definition.