# How to redirect/render Pyodide output in browser?

Tags: python, matplotlib, emscripten, webassembly, pyodide

I have recently come across the [Pyodide project](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide).

I have built a little demo using Pyodide, but although I've spent a lot of time looking at the source, it is not obvious (yet) to me how to redirect `print` output from python (other than modifying the CPython source), and also, how to redirect output from matplotlib.pyplot to the browser.

From the source code, [FigureCanvasWasm](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/packages/matplotlib/src/wasm_backend.py) does have a `show()` method with the appropriate backend for plotting to the browser canvas - however, it is not clear to me how to instantiate this class and invoke it's `show()` method or indeed, if there is another more obvious way of redirecting plots to canvas.

My questions therefore are:

1. How do I redirect `print()` messages
2. How do I force pyodide to plot matplotlib figures in the browser?

Here is my test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="../../pyodide/build/pyodide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
      pyodide.loadPackage(['matplotlib']).then(() => {
          pyodide.runPython(`
                  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                  plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
                  plt.ylabel('some numbers')
                  #fig = plt.gcf()
                  #fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')                  
                  print('Done from python!')`
          );
          //var image = pyodide.pyimport('imgdata');
          //console.log(image);
      });});

    </script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all let's see if we can get just anything to show up in the browser; e.g. a normal string. Python variables are stored in the [`pyodide.globals`](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/docs/api_reference.md#pyodideglobals) attribute. Hence we can take the python object from there and place it into a `<div>` element on the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="../pyodide/pyodide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
          pyodide.runPython(`my_string = "This is a python string." `);

          document.getElementById("textfield").innerText = pyodide.globals.my_string;
      });

    </script>

    <div id="textfield"></div>
<html>
```

Now I guess we can do the same with a matplotlib figure. The following would show a saved png image in the document.

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="../pyodide/pyodide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
      pyodide.loadPackage(['matplotlib']).then(() => {
          pyodide.runPython(`
                import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                import io, base64

                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                ax.plot([1,3,2])

                buf = io.BytesIO()
                fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
                buf.seek(0)
                img_str = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(buf.read()).decode('UTF-8')`
          );

          document.getElementById("pyplotfigure").src=pyodide.globals.img_str

      });});

    </script>

    <div id="textfield">A matplotlib figure:</div>
    <div id="pyplotdiv"><img id="pyplotfigure"/></div>
<html>
```

I haven't looked into the `backends.wasm_backend` yet, so that may allow for a more automated way of the above.

Comment: +1 This is a **fantastic** start. That's some mighty fine spelunking! ... :) however, I'm looking for a slightly more lower level of doing this (behind the scenes - as it were), so that a user could just run "normal" python scripts without having to resort to the mechanisms you employed. Ideally, I want to trap print() statements and all messages that are sent to the console.

Comment: Here are each of those examples live on codepen: [Example 1](https://codepen.io/aagostini/pen/gObgpvz), [Example 2](https://codepen.io/aagostini/pen/LYExVJL?editors=1000)

Answer (score 8):

When using the wasm backend, the canvas property of a figure is an instance of [FigureCanvasWasm](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/packages/matplotlib/src/wasm_backend.py). Calling the `show()` method of the canvas should be sufficient to display the figure in the browser. Unfortunately a minor bug in the `create_root_element()` method of the canvas prevents the figure from being displayed. This method creates a `div` element that will contain the figure. It tries first to create an iodide output div element. If that fails a plain HTML div element is created. This element however is never appended to the document and remains therefore invisible.

Below are the lines of code from [FigureCanvasWasm](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/packages/matplotlib/src/wasm_backend.py) were it happens

```
def create_root_element(self):
    # Designed to be overridden by subclasses for use in contexts other
    # than iodide.
    try:
        from js import iodide
        return iodide.output.element('div')
    except ImportError:
        return document.createElement('div')
```

The comment suggests the non-iodide code is a stub that needs to be extended, by overriding the method. This would require subclassing [FigureCanvasWasm](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/packages/matplotlib/src/wasm_backend.py), installing it as a pyodide module and configuring matplotlib to use that backend.

There is a shortcut however, because python allows overriding a method of an instance, without modifying the class, as per question [394770](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394770/override-a-method-at-instance-level). Putting the following code in your HTML document gives a figure in the browser

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from js import document

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)

# ordinary function to create a div
def create_root_element1(self):
    div = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(div)
    return div

#ordinary function to find an existing div
#you'll need to put a div with appropriate id somewhere in the document
def create_root_element2(self):
    return document.getElementById('figure1')

#override create_root_element method of canvas by one of the functions above
f.canvas.create_root_element = create_root_element1.__get__(
    create_root_element1, f.canvas.__class__)

f.canvas.show()
```

Initially the toolbar did not show icons. I had to download, unzip and install [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/download) alongside pyodide and include the following line in the header to get those

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Edit:
About the first part of your question, redirecting the output stream to the browser, you could take a look at how it is done in pyodide's [console.html](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/src/console.html).

It replaces sys.stdout by a StringIO object

```
pyodide.runPython(`
    import sys
    import io
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
`);
```

Then run the python code (that can be completely oblivious to the fact that it is running in a wasm context)

```
pyodide.runPython(`
    print("Hello, world!")
`);
```

Finally, send the contents of the stdout buffer to an output element

```
var stdout = pyodide.runPython("sys.stdout.getvalue()")
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = stdout;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Works well thanks ! Link for pyodide's console is broken though

Answer (score 5):

To show print() calls form pyodide you can use the parameters on loadPyodide to redirect stdout:

```py
var paragraph = document.getElementById("p");

pyodide = await loadPyodide({
    indexURL : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.1/full/",
    stdin: window.prompt,
    stdout: (text) => {paragraph.textContent += text;},
    stderr: (text) => {paragraph.textContent += text;}
  });
```

https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/blob/main/src/js/pyodide.js

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple interactive shell for Python. Read this [tutorial](https://karay.me/2022/07/12/bringing-python-to-the-web.html) if you need more detailed information.

```js
(async () => { // create anonymous async function to enable await

  var output = document.getElementById("output")
  var code = document.getElementById("code")
  
  output.value = 'Initializing...\n'

  window.pyodide = await loadPyodide({stdout: addToOutput, stderr: addToOutput}) // redirect stdout and stderr to addToOutput
        output.value += 'Ready!\n' 
})()


function addToOutput(s) {
  output.value += `${s}\n`
  output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight
}

async function evaluatePython() {
  addToOutput(`>>>${code.value}`)

  await pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports(code.value, addToOutput, addToOutput)
  try {
    let result = await pyodide.runPythonAsync(code.value)
    addToOutput(`${result}`)
  }
  catch (e) {
    addToOutput(`${e}`)
  }
  code.value = ''
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>

Output:
<textarea id="output" style="width: 100%;" rows="10" disabled=""></textarea>
<textarea id="code" rows="3">import numpy as np
np.ones((10,))
</textarea>
<button id="run" onclick="evaluatePython()">Run</button>
```

Here is the example for `matplotlib`. Note that this will load a bunch of dependencies which will take up to several minutes.

```js
const python_code = `
from js import document
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io, base64

def generate_plot_img():
  # get values from inputs
  mu = int(document.getElementById('mu').value)
  sigma = int(document.getElementById('sigma').value)
  # generate an interval
  x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
  # calculate PDF for each value in the x given mu and sigma and plot a line 
  plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
  # create buffer for an image
  buf = io.BytesIO()
  # copy the plot into the buffer
  plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
  buf.seek(0)
  # encode the image as Base64 string
  img_str = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(buf.read()).decode('UTF-8')
  # show the image
  img_tag = document.getElementById('fig')
  img_tag.src = img_str
  buf.close()
`;

(async () => { // create anonymous async function to enable await
  window.pyodide = await loadPyodide() 
  await pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports(python_code)
  await pyodide.runPythonAsync(python_code)

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>

mu:
<input id='mu' value='1' type="number">
<br><br>
sigma:
<input id='sigma' value='1' type="number">
<br><br>
<button onclick='pyodide.globals.get("generate_plot_img")()'>Plot</button>
<br>
<img id="fig" />
```