# Why do both x.__add__(y) and int.__add__(x, y) produce the same output?

Tags: python, int, addition, self

During the evaluation of `x + y`, under the hood Python calls `x.__add__(y)`. Why do both `x.__add__(y)` and `int.__add__(x, y)` produce the same output even when it is `object.__add__(self, other)` which contains **self**?

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the question

Comment: Those two things often produce the same result, but don't have to. Sfee here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46757134/2988730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the title, they don't in the general case, but they do in practice because you don't see methods being overridden at the instance level.

Normally, the call `x.method(y)` binds the function object `method` in the class to instance `x` before calling. The result is something equivalent to `type(x).method.__get__(x, type(x))(y)`.

For normal functions, the descriptor `__get__` operation returns a bound method object that is approximately a partial function object with the first argument filed in as `self`. You then call it with all the other arguments.

But what if you have something like this:

```
class C:
    def method(self, y):
        return y + 1

def method2(self, y):
    return y + 2

x = C()
x.method = method2.__get__(x, C)

print(C.method(x, 2))  # 3
print(x.method(2))     # 4
```

Since function objects are non-data descriptors, `x.method` will invoke the pre-bound method object in the instance dictionary instead of binding to the descriptor in the class dictionary.

`int` is an immutable class, mostly implemented in C, and you can't assign instance methods to it. So if `type(x) == int`, then `x.__add__(y)` is equivalent to `int.__add__.__get__(x, int)(y)`, which is functionally equivalent to `int.__add__(x, y)`.

The caveat here is that using dunder methods that implement operators has special behavior. Python optimizes the statement `x + y` to `type(x).__add__(x, y)`, not `x.__add__(y)`. As shown here, this saves on a couple of namespace lookups and a method binding operation. The consequence is that if you were to override `__add__` on an instance, the instance method would be ignored in favor of the class definition of `__add__`.

Comment: It's hard for me to get what you are saying.

Comment: @NSR. It's not a trivial topic to jump into. Read this in the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html. It will explain it much better than I can.