# Override a method by an attribute at instance level

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394770/5767535) however the methods described there do not work.

I have a certain class `Dog` with a method `woofwoof` and an attribute `woof`. There is a second method `bark` which returns `woofwoof()`. **For a given instance of `Dog`, I want to redefine `bark` so that it returns the value of `woof`.** Importantly, `bark` must remain a method given downstream code relies on calling `bark`.

See a minimum working example below.

```py
class Dog:
    woof = 'woof'
    def woofwoof(self):
        return 'woof woof'
    def woOof(self):
        return 'woOof'
    def bark(self):
        return self.woofwoof()

def test(foo):
    print(type(foo.bark))
    print(foo.bark())

foo = Dog()
test(foo)

foo.bark = foo.woOof
test(foo)

foo.bark = foo.woof
test(foo)
```

The above code yields:

```py
<class 'method'>
woof woof

<class 'method'>
woOof

<class 'str'>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

However the output I want from the last 2 lines is:

```py
<class 'method'>
woof
```

That is preserve the type of `bark` as a method, but make it return the value of attribute `woof` (in particular so that if I change the value of `woof` later on, `bark` returns the updated value when called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `foo.bark` has to be a callable, e.g. a function or method. You can't call a string. And even if you could, the assignment would set it to the current string, it wouldn't track changes to the attribute.

Define a method that returns `self.woof`, and assign that to `foo.bark`.

```
class Dog:
    woof = 'woof'
    def woofwoof(self):
        return 'woof woof'
    def woOof(self):
        return 'woOof'
    def bark(self):
        return self.woofwoof()
    def returnWoof(self):
        return self.woof

foo = Dog()
foo.bark = foo.returnWoof
test(foo)
```

Comment: I forgot to reply. All in all I found this to be the cleaner method and minimizing hassle, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the given instance, just redefine the method. At a high level, this is basically the same answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930897/218663 by @barmar which I upvoted.

The only difference here is that I'm not going to add in a utility method to the class `Dog()`, but monkey patch the instance via `functools.partial`. You might view this as a strength or a weakness of my solution.

```py
import functools

class Dog:
    woof = 'woof'

    def woofwoof(self):
        return 'woof woof'

    def bark(self):
        return self.woofwoof()

foo = Dog()
bar = Dog()

## ----------------
## for a given instace, return self.woof
## ----------------
foo.bark = functools.partial(lambda self: self.woof, foo)
## ----------------

print(foo.bark())
print(bar.bark())
```